Defining static array with gaps, where is it described in the standard?
If I have a static array defined with listing some elements and omitting others:
static int arr[] = {
   [1] = 1,
   [10] = 2,
   [5] = 3
};

This defines an array of size 11 with elements not mentioned in the list set to zero.
I remember, I saw description of this zeroing somewhere in documentation. But I can not find this piece now. Could you please point to me to a standard and chapter describing this?

"Set everything to zero" is defined here:
C23 6.7.11 §22

If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate is subject to default initialization.

Aggregate meaning array or struct.
Default initialization is a new C23 term but it is pretty much the same as in earlier versions of C, just more explicit regarding floating point and now supporting an empty initializer list {}:
C23 6.7.11 §11

If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, or any object is initialized with an empty initializer, then it is subject to default initialization, which initializes an object as follows:
/--/

if it has arithmetic type, and it does not have decimal floating type, it is initialized to (positive
or unsigned) zero;


Designated initializers are defined here:
C23 6.7.11 §17

Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated current object. /--/ ...a designation causes the following initializer to begin initialization of the subobject described by the designator. Initialization then continues forward in
order, beginning with the next subobject after that described by the designator.

Meaning if we do something like { [3] = 1, 1, 1 } then items at index 3,4 and 5 get set to the value 1. All other items get set to zero as per the previous quotes.

Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for.

c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf § 6.7.9 point 19:

... all subobjects that are not
initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

and point 10:

If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then: [...] — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero

Or latest draft § 6.7.10  points 20 and 11

Also, take a look at example 13 (same in both):
 37 EXAMPLE 13 Space can be “allocated” from both ends of an array by using a single designator:
int a[MAX] = {
    1, 3, 5, 7, 9, [MAX-5] = 8, 6, 4, 2, 0
};

38 In the above, if MAX is greater than ten, there will be some zero-valued elements in the middle; if it is less than ten, some of
the values provided by the first five initializers will be overridden by the second five.



If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate is subject to default initialization.
C2Xdr 6.7.10 22

... might be what OP wants.
